# Android: Call function if EditText has not been changed in x seconds

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have this app I'm working on, which sends requests to a server whenever text changes in the EditText. And it works fine as it is.

The problem is, that if I send a request every time the edittext changes, it will be a lot of requests in the end. And I don't want to use a "send" button.

I want something the works something like this:

If the user types in the edittext, some timer goes on. And if the timer reaches x seconds, it executes the request. But the timer resets if the user types again.

In this way, the request is only sent, once the user has stopped typing.

You might know some better way, and I'd be glad to hear it.

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method would be to use `myEditText.addTextChangedListener(...)` and use a `TextWatcher` to know when the text changes.

Then in the `onTextChanged()` method you can post a delayed runnable using a `Handler` to send the current text to your server if they don't type anything further.

Here is what this roughly looks like:

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
private Runnable postToServerRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO: PUT CODE HERE TO HANDLE CURRENT VALUE OF EDIT TEXT AND SEND TO SERVER
    }
};

private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // remove existing callback (timer reset)
        handler.removeCallbacks(postToServerRunnable);
        // 500 millisecond delay. Change to whatever delay you want.
        handler.postDelayed(postToServerRunnable, 500);
    }
};
```

Comment: I have to thank you, your answer did exactly what I needed :D

Answer (score 1):

There is this is method called `EditText.edittext.addtextchangedlistener` . add this listener to your edittext and override the methods like this.

```
   @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         called after the The complete Text is changed// this is what i think you should use
        }
```

I hope this is helpful . ThankYou.

Comment: I guess this could work, but I like the answer of George Mulligan more. But thanks for your time :D